# Number of arguments and point-free in Haskell

Tags: haskell, arguments, currying, pointfree

With multiple pattern-matching, different numbers of arguments are impossible, even with point-free!

```
foo True b = b + 2
foo _ = id
```

doesn't work for example. But

```
foo True = (+2)
foo _ = id
```

does. Sometimes we can use point-free only in one part of the function, so...

Why? Is it too hard for GHC? :'(

Comment: It's generally considered bad form.  Different number of arguments for a set of function definitions is generally indicative of an error.

Comment: It's possible to write well typed functions whose arity changes depending on the value of its arguments. Perhaps that's a minority sport, but it makes the restriction that left-hand sides must have the same number of arguments something of an artificial restriction, not to mention a nuisance. It's true that lhs mismatch is often an error, but why not let the type system catch them?

Comment: I think it's more convenient and readability is not affected. Checking that the types are the same and translating `id` to `(\x -> id x)` would be easy for the compiler, I guess.

Comment: It's a perfectly reasonable thing to allow varying number of arguments.  And it would be easy to compile.  The choice not to allow it is just a matter of style.

Comment: +1 I have wondered this myself.

Comment: See the `unpl` function of http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree which does that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why? Is it too hard for GHC?

**No**. It is not at all too hard for GHC. Actually, this is the fault of the Haskell Report.

See: [Haskell Report 2010 > Declarations and Bindings > Function bindings](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-840004.4.3.1)

> A function binding binds a variable to a function value. The general form of a function binding for variable x is:
>
> x p1<sub>1</sub> … p1<sub>**k**</sub> match1
>   …
>   x pn<sub>1</sub> … pn<sub>**k**</sub> matchn
>
> [...blah blah...]
>
> Translation: The general binding form for functions **is semantically equivalent** to the equation (i.e. simple pattern binding):
>
> x = \ x<sub>1</sub> … x<sub>k</sub> -> case (x<sub>1</sub>, …, x<sub>k</sub>) of
>
> (p11, …, p1k) match1
>   …
>   (pn1, …, pnk) matchn
>   where the x<sub>i</sub> are new identifiers.

(emphasis mine)

While function definitions are *semantically equivalent* to a lambda & case expression, they are not necessarily compiled that way, as Mihai suggests.

The thing is, the Haskell report *defines* function declarations such that they *must* have the same number of inputs on the left-hand side of the equation. This is made clear by the fact that `k` remains the same on both the 1st and the nth function declaration lines (and by implication, all lines in-between). *This* is the reason for the restriction; **it has nothing to do with GHC's implementation details**.

tl;dr

> The choice not to allow it is just a matter of style. – augustss

Comment: +1 for being the only one to address the real question.

Answer (score 4):

Each function equation *must* have the same number of arguments. This is why your first example fails.

To fix it, use

```
foo True b = b + 2
foo _ x = id x
```

As you see, both equations have the same number of arguments.

Multiple equations involving pattern matching are translated into case expressions. In your case `foo` gets translated roughly as

```
foo a b = case a of
    True -> b + 2
    _ -> id x
```

Both (all) branches of the `case` must have the same type, thus you first example which would be translated as

```
foo a b = case a of
    True -> b + 2
    _ -> id
```

is wrong because the branches have different types.

Of course, this is hand waving, the actual things happening behind the scenes are more complicated

Comment: But calling `foo ` with one argument does the same thing in both cases.

Comment: Simply expanding a simple function definition with one equation to a λ-expression explains very little here, what's more important is that definitions with _multiple_ equations are transformed into a _single_ equation with multiple `case` selections. Which doesn't really work when the equations are η-reduced to a different degree.

Comment: So pattern-matching on the left side desugars to a case expression?

Comment: @L01man: Yes, I think that's exactly how it works.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of something else. Updated the answer with the right explanation (thanks for @leftaroundabout which showed where I was wrong). Indeed, in the Core we have only `case` expressions for pattern matching